# SSRS Scale Out Deployment URLs

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have successfully setup a scale out deployment of 2 2016 Enterprise Edition SSRS servers connecting to a single shared database. So far, I have not setup a URL for the servers (they are each using their own local server name). Before I do that I'd like to better understand how this works.  There will not be a huge load on the server but it will be busier at certain times of the day. I am doing the scale out more for high availability than for any other reason.

1. Do I use the same URL for both the Server1 and Server2 Web Services and Web Portals
2. If I do use the same URLs and they are not load balanced, which server will the traffic be routed to or will it be random?
3. Could I use 2 different URLs and using one for Subscriptions and the other for ad-hoc report runs then switch the DNS pointers if there is a problem with one server.

This [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-scale-out-deployment) describes it in general but doesn't answer these questions specifically.